# About a battery's positive terminal

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrons, batteries, electrochemistry

Does the positive terminal of the battery mean that the concentration of electrons is more there. In some places people say that current moves from positive to negative and they call it a convention what does this really mean and others say it flows from negative to positive it's really confusing.

Comment: Why would you think that the concentration of electrons, which are negatively charged, would be at the battery terminal that is positively charged? How does that make sense?

Comment: current goes in the opposite direction of the electrons

Comment: So does that mean current flows from the negative to positive where charges are concentrated in the negative terminal but in terms with the conventional we identify the negative terminal as positive terminal and visa versa. And I thank everyone for clearing my doubt.

Comment: (a) "So does that mean current flows from the – to +". It's best to avoid "current flows" because it would mean "a flow of charge flows". It's negative charge that flows from the – terminal to the +. (b) "but in terms of the conventional we identify the negative terminal as positive terminal and vice versa" This is very confused. The – terminal is always the – and the +, is always the +. But the convention is to think of positive charge flowing through the external circuit from the + terminal to the –, whereas we now know that in a metal it's negatively charged electrons that flow from – to +.

Comment: So we assume that it flows from positive terminal to the negative terminal according to convention, whereas in reality in a wire current is from the negative to the positive terminal.

Comment: That's right. Good.  [But in some non-metals (such as electrolytes) it isn't electrons that carry the current. See John Doty's comment under my answer.]

Comment: But if we assume that current flows from positive to negative then most of our calculations might change. I'm currently learning about the magnetic effects of electric current and in that the poles
 of the magnetic field in a loop solely depends on the direction of the current (whether it is clock wise or anti clockwise). Here too I am confused .

Comment: Almost all the magnetic effects of a flow of positive charge in one direction are exactly the same as those of a flow of negative charge at the same rate in the opposite direction. An exception is the Hall effect.

Comment: Mathematically, if there are $\nu$ charged particles per unit volume, each with charge $q$ and all moving with velocity $\vec v$, then the current density vector is $\vec J=\nu q \vec v$. So if we swap $q$ for $-q$ and $\vec v$ for $-\vec v$, then $\vec J$ is unchanged. It is $\vec J$ on which most magnetic effects of a current depend.

Comment: Perhaps I was not critical enough of your earlier comment: "So we assume that it flows from positive terminal to the negative terminal according to convention, whereas in reality in a wire current is from the negative to the positive terminal." Better to replace "it" by "positive charge" and to replace  "current is from" by "current is the flow of negative charge from".

Comment: Another doubt regarding flow of electrons, is the current due to the concentration of electrons in the negative terminal that lead to the electrons to be pushed through the wire (as like charges charges repel each other) or is the concentration of electrons in the terminal causes the the electrons in the wire to be pushed to the positive side or are electrons attracted to the positive side or both the things happen when an battery is connected.

Comment: This is really a new topic. Please ask a new question. Hope you're now clear about conventional current.

Comment: Oh sorry, Thank you

Comment: You've done nothing wrong. Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names 'positive' and 'negative' were assigned to charges long before protons and electrons were discovered and even before batteries were invented. The type of charge that glass acquired when rubbed with silk was called 'positive', and the type that amber acquired when rubbed with fur was called 'negative'.

In the early 1800s batteries were invented and found to have opposite charges on their terminals. Hence their designations as 'negative' and 'positive' terminals. When wires were connected across the terminals, heating effects and (in the 1820s) magnetic effects were found and (in conjunction with the running down of the battery) attributed to a flow of charge through the wires. But no-one could know whether it was positive or negative charge or even both that was flowing. [The Hall effect had not been discovered, and few believed that atoms existed, let alone that there was such a thing as atomic structure.] So the decision was made to assume arbitrarily that it was positive charge that flowed through a metal wire from the positive battery terminal to the negative terminal. The 'hand rules' (invented in the later 1800s) that we can use in electromagnetism are based on this so-called *conventional current*.

In the 1890s, the negatively charged particles that we now call 'electrons' were discovered.  [Remember: negatively charged meant having the same kind of charge as amber rubbed with fur!] Within the next few years atomic structure came to be understood as electrons surrounding a nucleus, and electric current in a metal wire, as a flow of electrons. They flow from the negative battery terminal (with an excess of electrons) through the rest of the circuit to the positive terminal (with an electron deficit). Life would have been easier for 20th and 21st century high school students if, back in the 1700s, the decision had been made to call the type of charge that amber acquired when rubbed with fur 'positive'!

Comment: In a metal, we say current is carried by electrons (reality is trickier), but other things (ions, holes, positrons) can carry current, too. Some of these are positively charged. Since the electromagnetic effects of such current are the same, the convention we use is fine: sometimes the flow of carriers is in the same direction as the current, and sometimes it is opposite.